# Can we and how to use Urbanairship for iOS app Enterprise Distribution?

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm using Urbanairship for push notification in iOS development. So far it worked perfect during development using their development mode.

However, when I created the application using  their production mode, it never worked. When I changed to development mode without any other change to my code but the keys used by the ship , it would work. The airship can not send the test push notification through their web portal using the production mode, either.

I suspect it's because we're using the apple enterprise distribution programme (in house distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved by ensuring the app is running in production mode instead of development mode.

I re-did the following and it's ok now. 
1) apply a new push notification certificate for production in Apple developer portal. 
2) create a new production app in urbanairship and upload the certificate to UrbanAirship 
3) using the new keys got in steps 2) 
4) ensure the app is running in production mode. For me, I edit the scheme in XCODE,change the build configuration from debug to release for the Run command.